# Self-updating spreadsheet

Tags: excel, postgresql

Is it possible to create a spreadsheet that updates itself on a regular basis (daily, bi-weekly or monthly)? We use PostgreSQL. The content of the sheet is going to be based off a query I wrote.

What's the easiest way to connect an Excel spreadsheet to Postgres?

So far I have looked at: 
A Microsoft product: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-PostgreSQL-database-Power-Query-bf941e52-066f-4911-a41f-2493c39e69e4

PostgreSQL's ODBC: https://odbc.postgresql.org/

However I can't find a clear explanation of how I am practically going to set up the spreadsheet.

Comment: This post doesn't show any effort or research on your part.  What have you searched for, tried, and found to not work?

Comment: I ended up going with http://www.actualtech.com/'s solution and I couldn't be more satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A quick high-level explanation to connect excel to a database:**

You can connect to a ODBC enabled DBMS's view or table using Excel's `Get External Data` buttons. Specifically in the `Data` tab, the `From other Sources` button.

To use this, you need to create a new DSN for your connection. Start>>"Search Box">>ODBC and use the `64-bit ODBC administrator` to create a new System DSN. The DSN is the thing that will hold your ODBC connection's information, like the server address, username, password, etc...

Back in Excel you click the `From Other Sources` button in the `Data` tab and pick that DSN you just made. Then you can find the View you generated in Postgres and tell it which range you want to dump the data. That range then will hold the connection information so you can refresh any time you want.

Then, when you open the workbook you can just refresh the connection and pick up new data lickety-split.

There's other ways to connect Excel to ODBC and OLEDB enabled databases like using ADODB in VBA, but that's more complicated and probably overkill for you needs.